# jQuery file download hangs forever

Tags: jquery, download

Here's part of my HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="downloadFile()" value="Download">
<a href="http://i.imgur.com/CqIpg.jpg" id="fileLink">Link to file</a>
```

And here's the downloadFile code:

```
function downloadFile(){
 $.fileDownload($('#fileLink').attr('href'), {
   preparingMessageHtml: "We are preparing your report, please wait...",
   failMessageHtml: "There was a problem generating your report, please try again."
 });
 return false;
}
```

I'm using the [fileDownload plugin](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload) for jQuery. When I click the button the "We are preparing your report, please wait..." notification pops up. But it stays like that forever and the file doesn't download.

To ensure that the link is valid I click on the link and the file opens in the browser. Is there any point that I've forgotten to take note of?

Here's the [JSFiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeJM/zvxyv/2/)

Comment: your 'link' to file gets a 403 error. That could be your problem right there.

Comment: I've edited the code. The prior one was in my own server that's why you had no way of accessing it. But if you look at the jsfiddle you'll see that I'm right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this update to your demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/revive/zvxyv/14/

I've updated your code to include a click function and loaded the JS assets via jsfiddle, loaded on Dom Ready

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".button", function() {
        var href = $(this).next('a').prop('href');
        // alert to verify/check href value
        //alert(href);
        $.fileDownload(href, {
            preparingMessageHtml: "We are preparing your report, please wait...",
            failMessageHtml: "There was a problem generating your report, please try again."
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

It works now.. apparently the img URL you were using was blocking the cross domain cookie, or ?

Best of luck